# Unable to logging in file for CXF RS web Service

Tags: logging, jax-rs, cxf

I am trying to write in debug.log file in tomcat logs folder. Using logback / slf4j for logging.
Added : org.apache.cxf.Logger in classpath:/META-INF/cxf/.

updated rest-context.xml :

```
<cxf:bus>
      <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor" />
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>

</cxf:bus>
```

here is logback.xml :

```
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/logs" />

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${CATLINA_HOME}/logs/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<appender name="FILE-ERROR"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<!-- Send logs to both console and file audit -->
<logger name="com.ff" level="debug"
    additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
</root>
```

**Also I want to do logging in my DAO files and Service methods not only inboud and outbound messages.**
Please guide me where I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: I can see loggs for inbound and outbound in console but no in file.

Comment: As per my understanding its not loading logback.xml , because I removed file from classpath , it still generate inbound and outbound in console.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself.This link helped me to fix the issue :
https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Spring